# .xlsx to .csv with phpexcel creates readonly .csv file

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I am converting a .xlsx file `url-list-with-change-in-page-size.xlsx` to `url-list-with-change-in-page-size.csv` file using phpexcel library.

My code looks :

```
<?
/** SCRIPT SETTINGS */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** PHPExcel */
require_once 'PHPExcel.php'; // (this should include the autoloader)
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$excel_readers = array(
    'Excel5' , 
    'Excel2003XML' , 
    'Excel2007'
);



$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$path = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Wdrive/url-list-with-change-in-page-size.xlsx';
$excel = $reader->load($path);

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
$writer->save('/opt/lampp/htdocs/Wdrive/url-list-with-change-in-page-size.csv');
?>
```

this code successfully makes .csv file. but it is making `read only file` .

is there any way i can change or modify this code to make writable file programatically?

Thankyou

Comment: what happens if you change it to `$reader->setReadDataOnly(false); ` ?

Comment: PHPExcel simply creates a file, it doesn't make files read-only or read-write

Comment: What tells you that the csv file that you're generating is read only? Is it when you look at the file permissions? Is it trying to load it in MS Excel?

Comment: The issues were with the permissions of the folder where csv file resided.
Thanks all of you'll :)